# Jenkins pipeline : How can I display a downstream / upstream relationship?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, pipeline

I have a pipeline that ends with a step which call build() to run another pipeline, not waiting for its end.
Even when the downstream pipeline is finished, there is no downstream/upstream indication on each job page or build page.
Is there some trick to retrieve such a relationshi ?
Also, could it be possible to use the Downstream Build View plugin ?

Thanks for your help.
Best Regards
J.L.P.

Answer (score 2):

The upstream/downstream relationship is for Freestyle jobs only and does not work for Pipeline.  This is because [the internal (Java) Freestyle job API that the upstream/downstream feature uses to discover job relationships does not exist for Pipeline jobs](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-29913).  This also means that any 3rd-party upstream/downstream-related plugins such as the Downstream Build View plugin will not work for Pipeline jobs.

Since I also wanted to visualize upstream/downstream relationships for my Pipeline jobs, I ended up writing [a primitive plugin to do so](https://github.com/Poohblah/downstream-build-plugin) (it's a very bare-bones plugin written for my particular use case and I provide no support whatsoever; I'm just including this as an example of one way to visualize upstream/downstream relationships for Pipeline jobs).

Answer (score 1):

[Yet Another Build Visualizer](https://plugins.jenkins.io/yet-another-build-visualizer/) shows up- und downstream builds for pipeline jobs, too.

> A Jenkins plugin that allows visualization of the build flow of upstream and downstream builds in Jenkins.

Comment: this doenst seem to work for pipeline i my case